# php laravel mailchimp curl request not working

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

So i am trying to use a curl request to subscribe a user to mailchimp. I have followed some integration guides. The request works. I just a response of boolean false, not sure what i have missed here.

```
 $apiKey = *mailchimp api Key*;
 $server = *server*;
 $list = *mailchimp list id*;
 public function index(Request $request){       
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apiKey);
    $post = array(
      'apikey'=> $apiKey, 
      'email_address' =>  $request->input('EMAIL'),
      'status'        => 'subscribed',
      'merge_fields'  => array(
          'FNAME' => $request->input('FNAME'),
          'BIZNAME' => $request->input('BIZNAME')
       )
    );
    $json_data = json_encode($post);
    $url = "https://".$server.".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/".$list."/members/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $json_response = curl_exec($ch);
    header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
    curl_close($ch);
    return response()->json($json_response);
}
```

- i have tried some Laravel wrappers, but there are not many updated ones, hence trying to do it through curl.

Comment: Where is `$server` or `$list` set?

Comment: just outside the function, will include it for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out what the issue was @kerbholz, thanks for a point in the right direction. The server attribute is derived from the API key.

```
// get the server data center
  $server= substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);

// set the url 
  $url = "https://".$server.".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/".$list."/members";
```